# React native react-navigation variable inside other component

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

Inside my header component, there is a menu icon. When I press the icon, it should open the DrawerNavigation.

I already tried to add

```
const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
```

But unfortunately, it doesn't fix the problem.

My header component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image, Button } from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

import styles from '../assets/stylesheets/theme';

export default class Header extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.header}>
                <Icon onPress={() => navigate('DrawerToggle')} name="md-menu" style={styles.headerIcon} />
                <Image source={require('../assets/images/f1today.png')} resizeMode="contain" style={styles.headerLogo} />
                <View style={{ flex: 1 }} />
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

My home screen, where I import the header component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';

import Header from '../../components/header';

import styles from '../../assets/stylesheets/theme'

export default class HomeScreen extends Component {

    render() {
        return(
            <View style={styles.applicationView}>
                <Header />
                <Text>Home Screen</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

[This error appears when the icon inside the header is pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/152rh.png)

How can I use the navigation inside the header component? Thanks in advance.

**Update**

Header component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image, Button } from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

import styles from '../assets/stylesheets/theme';

export default class Header extends Component {
    render() {

        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

        return (
            <View style={styles.header}>
                <Icon onPress={this.props.navigate('DrawerToggle')} name="md-menu" style={styles.headerIcon} />
                <Image source={require('../assets/images/f1today.png')} resizeMode="contain" style={styles.headerLogo} />
                <View style={{ flex: 1 }} />
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Home screen:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';

import Header from '../../components/header';

import styles from '../../assets/stylesheets/theme'

export default class HomeScreen extends Component {

    render() {
        return(
            <View style={styles.applicationView}>
                <Header navigation={this.props.navigation} />
                <Text>Home Screen</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

[Error after update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98T3f.png)

Comment: Did you try passing the navigation to the header like this `<Header navigation={this.props.navigation} />`?

Comment: With your idea, I have a change the onPress of the icon from my header like this I guess?              `<Icon onPress={this.props.navigate('DrawerToggle')} name="md-menu" style={styles.headerIcon} />`

Comment: You already have this line here in your `Header` component `const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;` 
or you can pass the `navigate` function to your `Header` like this `<Header navigate={this.props.navigation.navigate} />`
And and the on press for the icon would be `onPress={this.props.navigate('DrawerToggle')}`

Comment: Please see my question, I updated my code

Comment: you're passing `navigation` to props and doing `this.props.navigate` on your Icon on press, which will be null. The on Press should be like this `<Icon onPress={this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerToggle')} />`.
Or you can just do `<Icon onPress={navigate('DrawerToggle')} />` since you have this `const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;` in your render function.

That should do it.

Comment: Now, when I click the icon, it doesn't give an error, but also, the DrawerNavigation doesn't appear. Secondly, there is a warning: https://imgur.com/a/vQKz5. The DrawerNavigation is open direcly when the app starts

Comment: I added an answer below.

Comment: please mark and vote if it solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the navigation object to your header component like this

```
<Header navigation={this.props.navigation} />
```

Your header component now should be something like this

```
export default class Header extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.header}>
                <Icon onPress={this.openDrawer.bind(this)} name="md-menu" style={styles.headerIcon} />
                <Image source={require('../assets/images/f1today.png')} resizeMode="contain" style={styles.headerLogo} />
                <View style={{ flex: 1 }} />
            </View>
        )
    }
    openDrawer() {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerToggle');
    }
}
```